# How to self reference a variable in a GitLab pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

The title is probably badly worded, but not sure how else to describe it.

In a GitLab project `.gitlab-ci.yml` file I have a job that needs to pass a variable. The variable *may* have been populated with content from an earlier step, or it may be undefined. In either case, I want to add content before passing on to the job's script.

Let me try to illustrate:

```
...
deploy_review:
  stage: deploy
  ...
  variables:
    HELM_EXTRA_ARGS: $HELM_EXTRA_ARGS --set a.b.c=$ANOTHER_VAR
```

As you can see, I'm trying to prepend any (potentially) existing value of `$HELM_EXTRA_ARGS` and append the `--set a.b.c=$ANOTHER_VAR`.

I tried some variations of what is shown, and they all throw an error when the job is run. I turned on script tracing to see if I could see anything that could tell me what's wrong. In all cases I would get something like the following:

```
'$HELM_EXTRA_ARGS' --set 'web_server.certificates.combined_cert=$COMBINED_CERT' --set web_server.certificates.combined_cert=[MASKED]
```

Really weird. It's almost like it's in various stages of variable substitution. This inevitably would cause the job to fail as the command being performed (`helm upgrade`) considered it invalid (which it is).

I finally managed to get this to work by just setting the variable without trying to self reference it:

```
HELM_EXTRA_ARGS: --set a.b.c=$ANOTHER_VAR
```

The problem with this, of course, is that if there was other content set to `$HELM_EXTRA_ARGS` prior to this job, they have been blown away.

Has anyone been able to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do in this case would be to do this in the job script, which (unlike using the GitLab yaml) allows you to rely on the semantics of your shell.

```yaml
before_script:
  - export HELM_EXTRA_ARGS="${HELM_EXTRA_ARGS} --set a.b.c=${ANOTHER_VAR}"
```

> The problem with this, of course, is that if there was other content set to $HELM_EXTRA_ARGS prior to this job, they have been blown away.

This shouldn't be a problem, exactly, because jobs environments are independent to begin with. If a previous job sets/modifies a variable, it should not affect the value of variables present in any other job.